# Some audio tracks become vorbis after encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, ac3

I encode a file with several audio tracks. Some of them must be copied (already AC3), some of them must be encoded (DTS to AC3). But tracks **0:a:8** and **0:a:9** become "vorbis" (5.1 and 2.0 respectively to original tracks) instead of AC3, that I specified. Why can it happen?
Here is what I do:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.FILE -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 448k -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy -c:a:8 ac3 -b:a:8 448k -c:a:9 copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:8 -map 0:a:9 OUTPUT.FILE
```

Thank you!

Comment: wrong order, at first mapping (this gives a new order), then with a new order a new numbering of streams

Comment: Not sure. Tried it and nothing changed. I have to add that all tracks get to OUTPUT in right order and first three tracks are converting just as I intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for `-map`, stream specifiers for output options refer to the order in the output.

So,

`-c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 448k -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy -c:a:3 ac3 -b:a:3 448k -c:a:4 copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:8 -map 0:a:9`

This will encode input `0:a:8` to AC-3 and copy `0:a:9`.

Comment: Thank you! This one worked!